# Page redirection issues with a popup/button (jQuery mobile)

Tags: jquery-mobile

I've created a button

```html
<a data-role="button">
```

inside a Popup. Here is Popup:

```html
<div data-role="popup" id="popupRegister" data-theme="a" data-dismissible="false">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" class="ui-header ui-bar-b" 
             role="banner">
        <h1 class="ui-title" role="heading" aria-level="1">Success!!</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="" data-theme="a" class="ui-body-a" 
       role="main" style="padding:15px;">
      <h1>Thank you for regestering with us.</h1>
      <p>You may now continue to the app.</p>

       <!-- this is the button -->
      <a href="#" id="takeMeHome" data-role="button" data-rel="back" 
       data-theme="a" data-inline="true" 
       data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" 
       data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" 
       class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-btn-up-a">
       <span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">GO</span></span>
      </a>       
     </div>
</div>
```

When I click the button, `console.log` is responding but page does not redirect. Why?
Here is how I redirect:

```js
$("#takeMeHome").click( function(){
    console.log("lets go home");
    //window.location.href = "home.html";
    //localStorage.registered=true;
    //window.location.replace("home.html");
    window.location.href = ("home.html");
});
```

Comment: use `$.mobile.changePage('home.html');` instead of `window.location.href = ("home.html");`.

Comment: $.mobile.changePage('home.html'); redirected the page but brings back to original page immediately.

Comment: add `data-history=false` attribute to the popup.

Comment: thanks, i spent 3 hours on that today, phew!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```js
window.location.href = ("home.html");
```

with

```js
$.mobile.changePage('home.html');
```

And add `data-history="false"` to popup div.